# How to deserialize XML with elements with same name, but different attributes and structure in c#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I have an XML response with the following structure:

```
 <Response>
    <Block id="1">
       <Some_Data_1><Some_Data_1>
       <Some_Data_2><Some_Data_2>
    </Block>
    <Block id="2">
        <Another_Data_3><Another_Data_3>
        <Another_Data_4><Another_Data_4>
        <Another_Data_5><Another_Data_5>
    </Block>
    <Block id="3">
        ...
    </Block>
</Response>
```

I need to deserialize each Block to the separate object in the fastest way.
So far I came up with manual searching for each block using LINQ, and deserializing each block separately, like that:

```
var Xblock1 = root.Elements("Block").FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("id")?.Value == "1");
Block1 block1 = (Block1)(serializer.Deserialize(Xblock1.CreateReader()));
```

But I believe there is more optimized way to do it.

Appreciate for your time

Answer (score 0):

Xml serialization is slow and requires a class and property name. Instead I recommend Xml Linq which is much faster and doesn't need predefined property names

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> dict = doc.Descendants("Block")
                .GroupBy(x => (int)x.Attribute("id"), y => y.Elements()
                    .GroupBy(a => a.Name.LocalName, b => (string)b)
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault()))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I need it eventually to be as objects? And I know all the property names, its not a problem

Comment: You ask for fast.  Create classes with object names (or anonymous) and use xml linx which is quicker than serialize.

Answer (score 0):

First method is with Serialize, second is a copy from the answer from @jdweng.

As said before, the method using `Serialize` is much slower!

For first method you also need a class generated by XSD.EXE which i linked at the end of this answer.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime start;

    start = DateTime.Now;
    XmlSerializer ser2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));
    FileStream f = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open);
    Response response = ser2.Deserialize(f) as Response;

    foreach (var item in response.Block)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.id);
    }
    f.Close();

    Console.WriteLine("Method 1: {0}", ((DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds / 1000));

    start = DateTime.Now;
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

    Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> dict = doc.Descendants("Block")
        .GroupBy(x => (int)x.Attribute("id"), y => y.Elements()
            .GroupBy(a => a.Name.LocalName, b => (string)b)
            .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault()))
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

    foreach (var item in dict.Keys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Method 2: {0}", ((DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds / 1000));

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

output:

```
1
2
3
Method 1: 0,0759927
1
2
3
Method 2: 0,0030262
```

Below codde is generated by `XSD.EXE /c file.xsd`, so from your XML you should create an XSD (which Visual Studio can do for you):

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.8.3928.0.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class Response {
    
    private ResponseBlock[] blockField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Block")]
    public ResponseBlock[] Block {
        get {
            return this.blockField;
        }
        set {
            this.blockField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class ResponseBlock {
    
    private string another_Data_3Field;
    
    private string another_Data_4Field;
    
    private string another_Data_5Field;
    
    private string some_Data_1Field;
    
    private string some_Data_2Field;
    
    private string[] textField;
    
    private byte idField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public string Another_Data_3 {
        get {
            return this.another_Data_3Field;
        }
        set {
            this.another_Data_3Field = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public string Another_Data_4 {
        get {
            return this.another_Data_4Field;
        }
        set {
            this.another_Data_4Field = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public string Another_Data_5 {
        get {
            return this.another_Data_5Field;
        }
        set {
            this.another_Data_5Field = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public string Some_Data_1 {
        get {
            return this.some_Data_1Field;
        }
        set {
            this.some_Data_1Field = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public string Some_Data_2 {
        get {
            return this.some_Data_2Field;
        }
        set {
            this.some_Data_2Field = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string[] Text {
        get {
            return this.textField;
        }
        set {
            this.textField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte id {
        get {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }
}
```